# Pass serializer: a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

In Active Model Serializers you can use a different Serializer by doing `respond with resource, serializer: ViewContractsSerializer`. The issue is that I want that to be dynamic by using `serializer: "View#{resource_name}Serializer"` and that does not work because it is a string. If i do `serializer: eval("View#{resource_name}Serializer")` it works of course, but I know that you should not use eval in production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has a helpful [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) method that can do what you want:

```
respond_with resource,
  serializer: "View#{resource_name}Serializer".constantize
```